# Visual Studio 2013 not letting me paste code

Tags: visual-studio-2013, copy-paste

I am using visual studio 2013 and I am trying to use ctrl+c and ctrl+v to copy and paste my code from notepad (or wherever) to visual studio but nothing happens. I researched the problem and people say that it is because remote desktop is running, but I am not using remote desktop on my computer. I have been able to copy and paste code from the same file in visual studio. thank you for any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by my antivirus Webroot. Explained here https://community.webroot.com/t5/Webroot-SecureAnywhere-Complete/Copy-Paste-Stops-Working-in-some-applications/td-p/21588#.UajauI7K48h you can fix this by going to settings in Identity Protection-> Application Protection and setting wdeexpress.exe to allow.